# Why subquery doesn't work in ON clause in DB2

Tags: db2, subquery, on-clause

Why this simple query works fine in oracle but doesn't work in DB2:

```
select * 
from 
sysibm.dual d1 
left join sysibm.dual d2 on 1=1 and exists (select 1 from sysibm.dual)
```

Moving subquery-involving condition to where clause may help, but that will restrain outer join into inner.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to run the query you have, I get a [`-338` error](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00338n.html), which according to Information Center (see link), there are the following restrictions on the `ON` clause:

> An ON clause associated with a JOIN operator or in a MERGE statement
>   is not valid for one of the following reasons.
>
> ```
> * The ON clause cannot include any subqueries.
> * Column references in an ON clause must only reference columns
>   of tables that are in the scope of the ON clause.
> * Scalar fullselects are not allowed in the expressions of an ON clause.
> * A function referenced in an ON clause of a full outer join 
>   must be deterministic and have no external action.
> * A dereference operation (->) cannot be used.
> * A SQL function or SQL method cannot be used.
> * The ON clause cannot include an XMLQUERY or XMLEXISTS expression.
> ```

I'm not sure if it's possible with your query, but do you think perhaps you could re-write something like this:

```
select * 
from 
sysibm.dual d1 
left join (
    SELECT dl.*,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.dual)
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END AS jn
    FROM sysibm.dual dl
) D2
  on 1=1 and 1=d2.jn
```

Comment: I could rewrite it but as I think joining a subquery as table could lead to full-scans. I have abstract examples:`1)select * from 
accounts a
join operations o on (o.acc_id=a.acc_id 
 and exists (select null 
             from operation 
             where acc_id=o.acc_id
             having max(ope_date)=o.ope_date))

2)select * from 
accounts a
join operations o on (o.acc_id=a.acc_id)
join (select max(ope_date) as ope_date,acc_id 
      from operations 
      group by acc_id) latestope 
 on (latestope.acc_id=o.acc_id and latestope.ope_date=o.ope_date)` Second one causes full scan as I think

Comment: The second query could be written like `SELECT *
FROM accounts a
JOIN operations o
  ON o.acc_id = a.acc_id
WHERE o.ope_date = (
 SELECT MAX(ope_date)
 FROM operations d
 WHERE o.acc_id = d.acc_id
)`

If you have an index that includes `o.acc_id` and `o.ope_date`, then DB2 will use the index to resolve the `MAX()`. We have a similar table here at `$work`, and a similar query runs very fast.

Answer (score 0):

This works in DB2 V10.1!
No fixpack installed.